# C strings size and array

Tags: c, arrays, string, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am facing a problem . I have the following sample

```
std::string key = "30 14 06 03 55 04 03 14 0D 2A";
```

when i found the size of the key string

```
 size_t sizee = key.size();
```

It comes out to be 29 that's fine.

but i want to be the output like this

```
char data[10];
data[0] = 0x30;
data[1] = 0x14;
data[2] = 0x06;
data[3] = 0x03;
data[4] = 0x55;
data[5] = 0x04;
data[6] = 0x03;
data[7] = 0x14;
data[8] = 0x0D;
data[9] = 0x2A;
```

The size should come as 10 considering 30 as one 14 as two.
this size should be the size of array as if the string become `00 01` the array size should be two.

Comment: its ok that you know what you want, but where is the question and that have you tried? and that is the actual target language? c or c++?

Comment: ...but your *string* **is** 29 characters long...

Comment: @vlad_tepesch how should i approach m not getting whether should i remove spaces first?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string key = "30 14 06 03 55 04 03 14 0D 2A";
    istringstream iss(key);
    vector<char> data;
    unsigned x;
    iss >> hex;
    while(iss >> x){
        data.push_back(x);
    }
    size_t size = data.size();
    cout << "char data[" << size << "];" << endl;
    for(int i=0;i < size ; ++i){
        cout << "data[" << i << "] = 0x" 
             << hex << uppercase << setw(2) << setfill('0') <<  (unsigned)data[i] << ';' << endl;
    }
}
```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string key = "30 14 06 03 55 04 03 14 0D 2A";
    istringstream iss(key);
    vector<char> data;
    unsigned x;
    iss >> hex;
    while(iss >> x){
        data.push_back(x);
    }
    size_t size = data.size();
    cout << "char content[" << size << "];" << endl;
    unsigned *content;
    content = (unsigned*)malloc(size*sizeof(unsigned));
    for(int i=0;i < size ; ++i){
        //cout << "data[" << i << "] = 0x" << hex << uppercase << setw(2) << setfill('0') <<  (unsigned)data[i] << endl;
        content[i]=data[i];
        cout << "content[" << i << "] = 0x" << hex << uppercase << setw(2) << setfill('0') <<  content[i] << endl;
    }
    if(content[0] == 0x30)
        cout << "I get it." << endl;
    free(content);
}
```

Comment: really thanks for the solution but i added the following lines in the code unsigned *content;content = (unsigned)malloc(size); for(int i=0;i < size ; ++i){ cout << "data[" << i << "] = 0x" << hex << uppercase << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (unsigned)data[i] << ';' << endl; content[i]=data[i]; cout<<"content[i] is" <<content[i]<<endl; } but i am nit getting content[i] as 0x30 and so on

Comment: @user3340847 ; should be `content = (unsigned*)malloc(size*sizeof(unsigned));`

Comment: sir i want this output content[0] = 0x30; content[1] = 0x14; content[2] = 0x06; content[3] = 0x03; content[4] = 0x55; content[5] = 0x04; content[6] = 0x03; content[7] = 0x14; content[8] = 0x0D; content[9] = 0x2A; from the following statementfor(int i=0;i < size ; ++i) { cout << "content[" << i << "]<<content[i] << ';' << endl; } how to get that

Comment: sir thanks for the reply but the problem is instead of this line cout << "content[" << i << "] = 0x" << hex << uppercase << setw(2) << setfill('0') <<  content[i] << endl; i want the same output from this line for(int i=0;i < size ; ++i) { cout << "content[" << i << "]<<content[i] << ';' << endl; } because if we only print content[i] we don't get the desired output (0x30) i want the conten[i] should be 0x30

Comment: @user3340847 content[i] is 0x30 if display `content[i] = 0x30`.

Comment: @user3340847 `48` is `0x30` as Hexadecimal display.

Comment: i want to remove the these  0x" 
             << hex << uppercase << setw(2) << setfill('0') keywords from cout and then print the content[i]=0x30

Comment: @user3340847 "_remove the these 0x" << hex << uppercase << setw(2) << setfill('0') keywords from cout and then print the content[i]=0x30_" Well, you can not have it. or use `printf`?

Comment: using printf also the content[i] is not 0x30 i want it to be 0x30 how to get that?

Comment: @user3340847 `0x30` : It is  only a matter of only display. Is no different as internal representation. try check `if(content[0] == 0x30)  cout << "yes" << endl else cout << "no" << endl;`

Comment: actually not display i want the data as 0x30 in content[i]

Comment: @user3340847 So try test this `if(content[0] == 0x30)  cout << "I get it." << endl;` at after `for`

Comment: can you just drop me a mail at cloverobert@gmail.com

Comment: i have one more query for you